# How to display odds (back/lay/draw) using betfair API

Tags: api, betfair

We have betfair API key and session key, but API documentation is relatable. We need to show data same as betfair shows. screenshot attached,

We are calling API for **listMarketBook** we got the data but don't know how this data will be show.

sample response:

https://gist.githubusercontent.com/manishoctal/7d30d4358ff38c56ba827f0fa4c91328/raw/ae0e7c3c008d3182dada39acdca8c7f77a1d1596/listMarketBook.json

[image: shot]

Answer (score 1):

Betfair subdivides its datasets so that one Event contains multiple Markets. Your screenshot is of an Event (Roma v AC Milan) containing multiple Markets (Match Odds, Over / Under 2.5 Goals, Half Time, Correct Score, etc.)

Your JSON example is the result of calling `listMarketBook()` on a single Market ID, which in this case is the Market ID (1.171451411) of Match Odds in the Lazio v Cagliari Event. Note that `numberOfRunners = 3` and `numberOfWinners = 1`, meaning that there will only be one result from three possible outcomes: Home win, Draw, Away win. Some markets may have more than one winner (e.g.: top 3 in a horse race).

For each runner, you can bet that a team will **win** (back) or will **not win** (lay). Note that a team "not winning" includes both lose and draw results, so your question "*How to display odds (back/lay/draw)*" confuses terminologies. You may back or lay a runner / team - and a team may win, lose or draw - but back/lay/draw are not all related possibilities.

The three `runners` in the JSON example each have their own `selectionId` and provide price information via `availableToBack` and `availableToLay`. These include the three best `price`s for each of back and lay, along with the amount of money available at each price in your currency unit (e.g.: euro). This is all the price information you are likely to need.

However, you still need to know what each selection means (e.g.: selectionId 56966 in the market 1.171451411 might mean Lazio). For that, you need to call [listMarketCatalogue()](https://docs.developer.betfair.com/display/1smk3cen4v3lu3yomq5qye0ni/listMarketCatalogue) with the marketId you used before (e.g.: 1.171451411). You'll also need to set the [MarketProjection](https://docs.developer.betfair.com/display/1smk3cen4v3lu3yomq5qye0ni/Betting+Enums#BettingEnums-MarketProjection) to determine the quantity of information you require (*pro-tip: ask for the minimum you require so as not to put unnecessary load on the Betfair API*).

Note that you should cache / store the results of `listMarketCatalogue()` and not regularly make the same request; and certainly not every time you request prices from `listMarketBook()`. The Market Catalogue rarely-if-ever changes and Betfair does not appreciate you making repeated, identical calls to this service.

Comment: Exactly!! Thanks for your answer @AJR, I update updated my screenshot that I want. We need to show Back, Draw, Lay may be you are trying to say (Selection1, Selection2, Selection3).

Comment: I think you need to be clear on what you're asking. Saying "Back / Lay / Draw" doesn't actually make sense. It's not the same as Win / Lose / Draw, which might be what you really want. Remember that any one of Selection 1, Selection 2 or Selection 3 (i.e.: Team A, Draw, Team B) could win, so you might Back them. But you can also Lay each result *including* the Draw ("The Draw will not happen"). So you actually have 3 (selections) x 2 (back or lay) = 6 possible options. This is why each runner has both availableToBack and availableToLay: . https://www.bookiebashing.net/glossary/laying-a-bet/

Comment: I should also say that the screenshot above appears only to display Back prices, not Lay prices. To display those, you simply take the values from runners.ex.availableToBack and ignore runners.ex.availableToLay. The API returns the three best prices and the amount of money available at those prices. You'll need to call listMarketCatalogue() to get the names of each selection (e.g.: Team A, Draw, Team B).

Comment: Hey @Cosmittus I've got market book data out for a soccer/football game. The information on display is either Home win, away win or draw naturally. My question is how do I get odds out of the information being fed back? It returns price and size...but how do you interpret this into the standard betting information that you see i.e. 5/2, 2/1 etc?

Comment: @logikurl: There are four main ways of expressing the same odds: fractional, decimal, US (moneyline) and probability. Betfair returns prices in decimal format (e.g.: 3.5). You're asking about fractional (e.g.: 5/2). Converting from fractional to decimal is easy (e.g.: 5/2 is 5÷2+1 = 3.5). Converting the other way is a bit harder. More information: https://www.bookiebashing.net/glossary/odds-explained/